# there is no 'opencv2/tracking.hpp' in opencv3.4.3 for Android

Tags: opencv

I'm making a Rock Paper Scissors application. Many people play the game and the application checks which type gets the victory. For real time check, I'm using **opencv3.4.3 in Android**. To detect the hand, I'm going to use 'Tracker' but **there is no 'opencv2/tracking.hpp'**. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: studio version is 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Tracker.hpp is available in the openCV_contrib folder which require a separate download. You can get the required files here https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib